# Setting a cookie in Apache Components HttpClient but unable to retrieve at the server in HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, cookies, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm adding a cookie to Closeable HttpClient object and attempt to retrieve the same at the Server as below.

```
BasicClientCookie mCookie = new BasicClientCookie("myCookie", "dummyValue");
    mCookie.setDomain(".myCookie.net");
    mCookie.setPath("/");
    mCookie.setSecure(true);
    mCookie.setAttribute(ClientCookie.PATH_ATTR, "/");
    mCookie.setAttribute(ClientCookie.DOMAIN_ATTR, ".myCookie.net");
    mfCookies[0] = mCookie;

    BasicCookieStore basicCookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    basicCookieStore.addCookies(mfCookies);

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(
            RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeOut).build())
        .setDefaultCookieStore(basicCookieStore)
        .setConnectionManager(poolingConnectionManager)
        .build();
```

I connect to local url using HttpGet object as below

```
httpGet = new HttpGet(myLocalUrl);
httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

HttpClient hits the local url correctly connecting to Rest end point on local host but when I try to retrieve cookies using code below

```
(HttpServletRequest) request.getCookies() ;//returns null
```

I get null.

Can someone please help - I'm using spring boot to make a Rest end point (server) and attempt to retrive the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself, actually I was setting the domain as .myCookie.net while I was connecting to http://localhost:8080/..., if running on local, the localhost should resolve to the domain name by dns so in this case .myCookie.net should be mapped to localhost in file /etc/hosts file.
eg set 127.0.0.1  [www.myCookie.net](http://www.myCookie.net) in etc/hosts file and hit the url http://www.myCookie.net/...

If the url the httpclient connects to and the domain set in the cookie dont match, httpclient will just drop the cookies.